# How to get values from jTable and store in a database?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am not able to understand how to get the values entered in a jTable and store them in a database. Can anyone please help me with the code.

Comment: How have you modeled the data?  That is what method is been used to get the data to display in the JTable (via the TableModel)?

Comment: Which database and IDE do you use?

Answer (score 3):

This can be used for getting values from jTable and inserting into database,before this create proper connection with your database.

```
dbStatement=con.createStatement();
for(int i=0;i<=jTable1.getRowCount;i++){

                String item=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                String quant=jTable1.getValueAt(i,2 ).toString();
                String unit=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                String tot=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();

                dbStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES('"+item+"','"+quant+"','"+unit+"','"+tot+"')");

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/563660/GUI/java/Populate-JTable-Database-Data) . After then any error there then put your code as well as error line so that this community will help you. This is not the place where you ask for the full code from the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve data from a Jtable you can use the most concrete method:

```
Object value = jtable.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

Following the codeflow you should open a database connection, using mysql for example:

```
// driver registration
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

// create a connection
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server_name/database_name","user", "password");

// create a statement
Statement s = connection.createStatement();

// execute a query, this method will return the number of affected rows
int count = s.executeUpdate ("insert into some_table(value) values('" + value + "'));
```

Comment: For readability you should call `conexion` a `connection` and it's a connection.

Comment: That happen when it is not your native tongue :p